Bar-type conditional formatting within tabular
Within the tabular environment, I wanted to achieve (coloured) horizontal bars whose lengths correspond to the cell value. The idea is analogous to a conditional formatting option in most spreadsheet programs.
There is already a solution for colouring the whole cell,
and after looking around, I modified it like this:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

\begin{document}

% cc for Conditional (format) Column. Just roll with it.
\newlength\ccwidth

% the formatting macro
\newcommand{\ApplyCondBar}[1]{%
    % two cases: numbers from 0 to 1, or from 0 to 100
    \ifdim #1 pt > 1 pt
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cbarwidth}{#1 / 100 * \ccwidth}
    \else
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cbarwidth}{#1 * \ccwidth}
    \fi
    \hspace{-\tabcolsep}%
    \colorbox[RGB]{160,224,181}{%
        \vphantom{#1}%
        \hspace{\cbarwidth pt}%
    }

    \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
    \hfil#1\hfil
}

% inserted setting \ccwidth here, so that we can access it in the macro
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\setlength{\ccwidth}{#1}\collectcell\ApplyCondBar}p{#1}<{\endcollectcell}}

%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} % fine, but the box doesn't grow vertically
%\setlength{\fboxsep}{1mm} % added to box size, still fine.
%\setlength{\fboxsep}{2mm} % too large, breaks the solution.
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % breaks the solution.
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt} % breaks the solution.

\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|*{10}{R{1cm}|}}
            1.00 & 0.99 & 0.82 & 0.37 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.5 & 0.3 & 1.00 & 0.90 \\
            \hline
            0.5 & 0.3 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.37 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}

Output:

It's an okay starting point, I think, but it could use some improvements:

The bar isn't centered (\hspace{-\tabcolsep} moved it to the left, but using \hspace{-0.5\tabcolsep} breaks it...),
the \hline touches the bar below it, but not the one above, and
the vertical lines seem to be partially covered by the bars.

It's also not particularly stable. I added some comments right before the table, with some settings that break the formatting - typically by putting the bar and cell content on different lines.
So, for one, I wanted to put it out there for anyone who's interested, but I'd also like to hear some suggestions for improvement. For these kinds of things, my (La)TeX knowledge isn't quite sufficient, I think.

I'd set \tabcolsep to zero and also \fboxsep, because \colorbox adds a padding like for \fbox.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

% cc for Conditional (format) Column. Just roll with it.
\newlength\ccwidth

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpcompareTF \fp_compare:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

% the formatting macro
\newcommand{\ApplyCondBar}[1]{%
  % two cases: numbers from 0 to 1, or from 0 to 100
  \fpcompareTF{#1>1}{%
    \edef\cbarwidth{\fpeval{#1 / 100 * \ccwidth}}%
  }{%
    \edef\cbarwidth{\fpeval{#1 * \ccwidth}}%
  }%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \colorbox[RGB]{160,224,181}{\strut\hspace{\cbarwidth pt}}%
  }%
  \hfil#1\hfil
}

% inserted setting \ccwidth here, so that we can access it in the macro
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{%
  >{\setlength{\ccwidth}{#1}\collectcell\ApplyCondBar}p{#1}<{\endcollectcell}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{|*{10}{R{1cm}|}}
1.00 & 0.99 & 0.82 & 0.37 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.5 & 0.3 & 1.00 & 0.90 \\
\hline
0.5 & 0.3 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.37 \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|*{10}{R{1cm}|}}
100 & 99 & 82 & 37 & 98 & 96 & 59 & 30 & 100 & 90 \\
\hline
50 & 30 & 100 & 100 & 99 & 98 & 96 & 90 & 82 & 37 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}

Using \fpcompareTF and \fpeval is handier than \pgfmathparse.

